# Errors displaying buffered image

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have recently been following a tutorial on how to make a 2D game in java. I know all the concepts and I am using the video as a guide line so that I can get everything setup and then start pumping all of my ideas and content into the skeleton.

I was following this(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE7ezYCTPe4) tutorial when I ran into a problem. About 28 minutes into the video I type this code:

```
public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

This was all fine until I tried to run it. He runs it in the video and it works just fine, but when I run it I get an error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
>       at com.kaperly.game.Game.render(Game.java:102)
>       at com.kaperly.game.Game.run(Game.java:83)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I would really like to continue the video and be on my way to making my first fully functional game (All other game attempts never made it to functional stages.)

Comment: You didn't include a link to the tutorial..

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it now.

Comment: Did you search the forum/web for examples that use the buffer strategy class? The code you posted isn't complete, but I would guess it is saying that the frame must be visible or packed before you can access its buffers.